# Convert number in sci format to string in excel

Tags: excel

I need to convert a column of alpha-numeric values to strings in an Excel function. CStr(value) works fine, **UNLESS** the value is something like 123E4. In that case, Excel treats the value as 1230000 and returns the string "1230000". Using Format(value,"#") yields the same result. The result I want is the string "123E4".

How can I get this?

The input cells are downloaded from a web site. They use the "General" format. I pass the value in a cell to the following function.

```
Function Var2Str(varA1 As Variant, Optional strFmt As String = "#") As String
Dim strTry As String
Dim strMsg As String
Debug.Print varA1, VarType(varA1), TypeName(varA1)
strTry = CStr(varA1)
Select Case VarType(varA1)
Case vbDouble
        strTry = Format(varA1, strFmt)
Case vbString
    'no further action
Case Else
    strMsg = "Unhandled VarType in Var2Str" _
        & vbCrLf & vbTab & "vara1 = " & varA1 _
        & vbCrLf & vbTab & "varType = " _
        & VarType(varA1) & vbCrLf & vbTab _
        & "TypeName = " & TypeName(varA1)
    MsgBox strMsg, vbOKOnly, "Information"
End Select
Var2Str = strTry
Debug.Print Var2Str
```

End Function

Comment: How are the cells containing the input values formatted?

Comment: With "123E4" formatted as text i get the same value "123E4" out.  You could try `format(cell, cell.numberformat)` depending on how your cells are formatted.  Might help to show the actual code you're using in context.

Comment: How, exactly, are they downloaded into Excel?  And how is it that a downloaded file is able to set a cell in your worksheet to the `General` format?  You will need format the cell as text *before* the data is placed on the worksheet, or tell Excel to treat the entry as text.

Comment: I export a table of data to a .csv file, then run several VBA procedures to analyze it. One of the columns in the .csv file contains alphanumeric values like 123876, 23XY45, 123E4. By default, when the .csv file is opened in Excel, all columns have the General format. See my edited post for the exact code I am using.

Comment: There is no need to reformat the cell as TEXT. Please see answer below.

Comment: There might be some challenging cases, when combining different number of significant digits and varying column width. E.g., `1.2e8`.

Comment: Did you find any contribution useful? Please remember giving feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could try (1) getting what you see in a string, and (2) using that to set the value of the target cell.

```
Sub test_format2()
    Dim r As Range, r1 As Range
    Set r = Selection
    For Each r1 In r
        Dim n1 As String
        n1 = r1.Text                              ' (1)
        r1.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "'" & n1        ' (2)
    Next r1
End Sub
```

This seems to be the only bullet proof option.
For instance, 1.2e8 seems to be a challenging case when varying column width.

Answer (score 0):

Variations on this question are common here. An oz of prevention is worth a pound of cure.  So best to prevent the problem instead of trying to cure it after the fact:

In order to prevent Excel from converting certain alpha-numeric data that look like numbers or dates, into numbers or dates, you must **IMPORT** rather than **OPEN** the file.  When you do that, the Text-import-wizard will open and you can designate the column as text **before** excel does the conversion.

Exactly how to do this depends on your version of Excel.  In more recent versions, it will be on the `Get & Transform` tab on the `Data` Ribbon and may say something like `From Text/CSV`.

If you need to automate this, you can record a VBA macro while doing it.

[image]

I entered the values you listed above in a document using Notepad, and saved it as a csv file.

I then used the above method and got this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution was to use Workbook.OpenText to open the downloaded files and use the fieldinfo parameter to force the relevant columns to be formatted as text. The only trick is to make sure the downloaded file name has extension .txt, not.csv. For unknown reasons, VBA will not respect the fieldinfo parameter to open files with the .csv extension, regardless of the file content.